# Flowplayer volume slider extending from center

Tags: flowplayer

On one video on my site (so far) out of hundreds that work as expected, I get a weird hiccup in the rendering of the volume control.

Rather than a left to right slider, the slider extends from the center out to the sides.  I haven't seen this option in flowplayer before, but if it is an "option" I need to figure out what it is so I can identify why it is happening and correct or countermand it.

[image: Centered Volume Slider 1]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sigh.

Bad content.  I traced it back far enough and found that the content (despite being text-align: center) was wrapped in a center tag... admonished content creator, moved on.